# Gradle Api Sources and Doc when writing Gradle Plugins

Tags: eclipse, gradle

#### The question:

How do I get the sources and javadoc/groovydoc for the gradle-api code integrated into an Eclipse project?

#### Background:

I'm using Gradle to build a Gradle-plugin that I'm writing. I'm using Eclipse as an IDE for this project and my Gradle script for building this plugin is using the 'Eclipse' plugin to generate my Eclipse project. Also, I'm using Spring's Gradle plugin for Eclipse which grabs all my dependencies from my build.gradle file.

The dependencies block for this Gradle script has

```
dependencies {
    compile localGroovy()
    compile gradleApi()
    // I want something like: 'compile gradleApiSources()' here
    // I want something like: 'compile gradleApiDoc()' here as well
}
```

#### Justification:

As I'm learning to write Gradle plugins, it would be helpful to be able to see the documentation and even implementation for Gradle to help me learn what I'm doing.

Comment: The related bug https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1003

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me in Eclipse:

```
plugins.withType(EclipsePlugin) {
    plugins.withType(JavaBasePlugin) {
        eclipse {
            classpath {
                file {
                    whenMerged { classpath ->
                        String gradleHome = gradle.getGradleHomeDir()
                            .absolutePath
                            .replace(File.separator, '/')
                        String gradleSourceDirectory = "${gradleHome}/src"
                        classpath.entries.each { entry ->
                            if (entry in org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.AbstractLibrary
                                    && entry.library.path.contains('generated-gradle-jars')) {
                                entry.sourcePath =
                                    new org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.internal.FileReferenceFactory()
                                        .fromPath(gradleSourceDirectory)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that your Gradle Home contains the source directory. If you use the wrapper this can be done by updating the `distributionUrl` to an `-all` version in the wrapper task.

You will also need to stop the Gradle daemons that are running [otherwise they will keep their own "home"](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html#getGradleHomeDir--): `./gradlew --stop`, then you can go ahead and run the task: `./gradlew eclipse`

See [GRADLE-2133](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2133?focusedCommentId=17906&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17906) (which this answer was adapted from)

Comment: If I replace sourcePath with gradleSrc then it work for me for the distribution https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-all.zip

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer for eclipse but I can tell you how I do this for intellij which might give you some inspiration. It would be nice if this were available more easily.

```
private void addGradleSourceDeps() {
    PathFactory pf = new PathFactory()
    pf.addPathVariable('GRADLE_HOME', project.gradle.gradleHomeDir)
    project.extensions.idea.module.iml.whenMerged { Module module ->
        module.dependencies.grep {
            it instanceof ModuleLibrary && ((ModuleLibrary) it).classes.grep { Path path ->
                path.relPath.substring(path.relPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).startsWith('gradle-')
            }
        }.each { ModuleLibrary lib ->
            // TODO this needs to be fixed for gradle 1.9 which now includes separate sub directory for each jar
            // for now a workaround is to execute the following
            // cd $GRADLE_HOME
            // for each in $(find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d ! -name META\-INF); do cp -a ${each} .;done
            lib.sources.add(pf.path('file://$GRADLE_HOME$/src'))
        }
        module.dependencies.grep {
            it instanceof ModuleLibrary && ((ModuleLibrary) it).classes.grep { Path path ->
                path.relPath.substring(path.relPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).startsWith('groovy-all')
            }
        }.each { ModuleLibrary lib -> lib.sources.add(pf.path('file://$GROOVY_SRC_HOME$')) }
    }
}
```

This relies on me having installed a gradle src distribution into a location available via the GRADLE_HOME path variable in intellij (and similar for GROOVY_SRC_HOME). You can also see my plugin currently uses gradle 1.8, the src layout changed in 1.9 so I need to fix this when I upgrade.